# regex - match last occurrence group

Tags: regex

Example string: `'100 foo 100 bar asdfasdf asdfasdf frqf 200 foo 200 bar asdfsd FOOBAR'`

I want to match out the latest occurrence of digits followed by foo and digits followed by bar, which precedes FOOBAR

Expected: [200, 200]

Current Output: [100, 100]

this is what I have:

```
r'(\d+.?\d+)\s*foo.*?(\d+.?\d+).*bar(?:.|\n)*(?:FOOBAR)\s?(\d+.?\d+).*?'
```

Comment: What language are you using? Does it support lookahead and lookbehind?

Comment: Should FOOBAR be present in the string? And only a single occurrence of FOOBAR?

Answer (score 0):

If the language you're using supports negative lookahead, you should try-

`(\d+) foo (\d+) bar(?:(?!(\d+) foo (\d+) bar).)*?FOOBAR`

Check out the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fA6wE2/289)

Explanation:-

- First we check for the `digits foo digits bar` group using `(\d+) foo (\d+) bar`
- Now we make sure there's not another occurence of `digits foo digits bar anything` right afterwards using a negative lookahead - `(?!(\d+) foo (\d+) bar).`

  We now wrap this inside a non capturing group and do a lazy quantifier on it.
- Finally, check for `FOOBAR` at the end

Essentially this makes sure, the digit groups captured in here-

`(\d+) foo (\d+) bar`

**are not followed** by any other `digits foo digits bar` before reaching `FOOBAR`.